# Cakephp RESTful routing with Plugin

Tags: cakephp, routes

Using Cake 2.x I am trying to route RESTful traffic to my Users controller to my UserManagement plugin.

My routes are as follows:

```
// re-redirect root traffic to login
Router::connect('/', array('plugin'=>'UserManagement','controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));  

CakePlugin::routes();  
Router::mapResources(['users']);

Router::parseExtensions();
```

I also tried:

```
Router::mapResources(['UserManagement']);
```

When I call the resful url I get the following error:

```
users/1.json

{
    "code": 404,
    "name": "Action UsersController::51() could not be found.",
    "message": "Action UsersController::51() could not be found.",
    "url": "\/users\/51.json"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following CakePHPs convention over configuration approach, you specify plugins like you do anywhere else, using the plugin syntax, ie prepend the plugin name and separate it with a dot from the controller name

```
Router::mapResources('UserManagement.Users');
```

This will of course also require you to use the plugin name in the request URL, ie

```
/user_management/users/51.json
```

instead of only

```
/users/51.json
```

If you'd wanted to use the latter, but still connect to the plugin, then you could try the `prefix` option trick, that is, supply the default value of `/`, which stops the router from using the plugin name as the prefix (not to be confused with actual [**prefix routing**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)).

```
Router::mapResources('UserManagement.Users', array(
    'prefix' => '/'
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Using a Plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-use-plugins.html#using-a-plugin)**
- **[Cookbook > Appendencies > Glossary > Plugin Syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-plugin-syntax)**

Comment: thank you but that still does not work - 404 "name": "Action UsersController::51() could not be found.",

Comment: @AlanA Probably because you are missing the plugin name in the URL, ie you are accessing `/users/51.json`, instead of the required `/user_management/users/51.json`. If what you are after is the former format, ie using `/users/...` while connecting to the plugin, then please point that out in your question.

Comment: yes I was using just the controller name in url as written in my question. Using the plugin name works though :) If I want to just use the 'user's and not the plugin name in the url is that also possible?

Comment: @AlanA With `mapResources()` only via kind of a "trick", that is by supplying the default `prefix` option of `/`, which will stop using the plugin as the prefix (not to be confused with prefix routing). See also my updated answer.